# UISearchBar - addSubview issue?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisearchbar

I'm trying to add `UISearchBar` (fixed position!) on top of the `UITableView`.

```
CGRect rect = self.headerView.frame;
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0,
                            rect.origin.y + rect.size.height,
                            rect.size.width,
                            CZP_SEARCHBAR_HEIGHT);

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:newRect];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Result (i got a white rect on position where i want my bar):

[image]

But if i want to add subview to my view, searchbar appear on 1st cell of tableview (below my view!)

```
[view addSubview:searchBar];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. It looks like you're trying to do it in code instead of a storyboard, so this is a code example. It also looks like you're doing it in a popover of sorts, I put together a quick project as an example that uses a popover, it doesn't look exactly like yours, but it's close enough to get you where you're trying to go I think.

First, here's the code sample, this is from the view controller that contains the header, search bar and tableview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // get the desired size for this popover and setup our header height
    CGSize viewSize      = self.preferredContentSize; // could also be self.view.bounds.size depending on where you're using it
    CGFloat headerHeight = 44.0;

    // setup our desired frames
    CGRect headerFrame          = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewSize.width, headerHeight);
    CGRect searchContainerFrame = CGRectMake(0, headerHeight, viewSize.width, headerHeight);

    // for this frame I'm simply centering it, there's better ways to do it but this is an example
    CGRect searchBarFrame       = CGRectMake(5, 5, searchContainerFrame.size.width - 10, searchContainerFrame.size.height - 10);

    // set our tableview frame to be positioned below our header and search container frame
    CGRect tableviewFrame       = CGRectMake(0, headerHeight *2, viewSize.width, viewSize.height - (headerHeight * 2));

    // create our header view and set it's background color
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    // create our container view to hold the search bar (not needed really, but if you want it contained in a view here's how)
    UIView *searchContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:searchContainerFrame];
    searchContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    // instantiate our search bar
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:searchBarFrame];

    // add the search bar to the container view
    [searchContainer addSubview:searchBar];

    // create our tableview and position it below our header and search containers
    UITableView *tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableviewFrame];
    tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [self.view addSubview:headerView];
    [self.view addSubview:searchContainer];
    [self.view addSubview:tableview];
}
```

That snippet gives me a popover with an orange header, a green/grey search bar and a tableview beneath it.

[image]

EDIT: If you're interested in looking through the project file that I used to put this together you can download it off github [here](https://github.com/appteur/popover_with_tableviewSearch/tree/master)